# Reliable Markdown parser written in PHP that uses tokenization

Tags: php, parsing, markdown

Is there a Markdown parser out there that uses tokenization rather than relying on regular expression matching?

From looking at [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), it seems pretty easy to implement, so I was thinking to write one, but I'd like to know if someone did it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try taking a look at [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

It's written in Haskell, but it builds an AST ([without using regular expressions](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html#a-simple-example)).

See ["Scripting with Pandoc"](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) for a more in-depth description.